# Redirect loop when removing www in with RewriteEngine

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

**Note: I have seen other questions/answers for redirecting www->non-www. This is more to know WHY this isn't working**

So I have a VirtualHost file that looks roughly like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ...
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301]
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try it I keep getting a redirect loop. I don't see anything telling me *what* it's redirecting to in the access logs.

I suspect it keeps erroneously going to www.domain.com instead of to domain.com, even though I'm sure this should be correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You're probably getting into loop due to use of `%{SERVER_NAME}` variable.

Comment: Am I not referencing it correctly? According to here this seems right
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Yes I know that doc too but probably `%{SERVER_NAME}` is getting set to `www.domain.com`. Did you try this suggested rule?

Comment: It worked! I'll mark it as answered later, although I just want to see if anyone else has thoughts on why the variable wasn't set correctly

Comment: Hmm I suspect it is due to `ServerAlias` line.